# C++ class design issue on inheritance

Tags: c++

I inherited some code that was developed for Linux and Mac OS. Now, I'm porting it on Windows using visual studio. When I tried to built it with visual studio 2010 I got the error listed below.
The simplified class's structure is reported in the following.

Consider the `Node` class:

```
    class Node
    {
    public:

        Node();    
        virtual ~Node(){}

        virtual bool isLeaf() const = 0;
        /* other methods */
        virtual vector<Node *>& getNodeList() const=0;
    };
```

Where `isLeaf` and `getNodeList` are pure virtual methods.

Then two derived classes `LeafNode`

```
class LeafNode : public Node
{
public:
    LeafNode(){ cout << "leaf constructor";}  
    ~LeafNode(){ cout << "leaf destructor";}
    bool isLeaf() const { return true; }
    vector<Node *>& getNodeList() const {}

};
```

Which implements just the `isLeaf` method, and  `CompositeNode`:

```
    class CompositeNode : public Node
    {
    public:
        CompositeNode(){ cout << "CompositeNode constructor";}
        ~CompositeNode(){ cout << "CompositeNode destructor";}
        bool isLeaf() const { return false;}
        vector<Node *>& getNodeList() const{ 
              return m_NodeList;
        }

    private:
        vector<Node*> m_NodeList


    };
```

Which implements both pure virtual methods.
If I try to build this code with visual studio I get the following error:

```
error C4716: 'LeafNode::getNodeList()' : must return a value
```

I understand the compiler, but I don't know how to manage this situation.
How should I redesign the class to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wonder that this code should have compiled with g++, clang, or any other C++ compiler. IMHO, every C++ compiler should yield similar errors like VC++ in this case.

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance or classes.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the compiler, but I don't know how to manage this situation. How should I redesign the class to solve this problem?

`LeafNode::getNodeList` can only return an empty list. Implement it as:

```
vector<Node *>& getNodeList() const
{
   static vector<Node *> empty;
   return empty;
}
```

Also,

```
virtual void isLeaf() const = 0;
```

is not right. It makes more sense to use:

```
virtual bool isLeaf() const = 0;
```

Comment: You are right, the isLeaf should return a bool. So, in general it is correct to return a static empty data structure in these cases?

Comment: @paperox, sort of. Ideally, you want to make the return value a `vector<Node*> const&` so the calling functions don't modify the returned object.

Comment: @paperox - If the function can't fulfill it's , well *function*, one must wonder why it's a required part of the interface. You can also throw an exception, but that's lazy IMO. The design should be improved and not have an interface member that cannot be implemented.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks for your reply. This is ok for now, but how can I redesign the interface to improve it. Should I move the `getNodeList` in another class using multiple inheritance?